# How to gain both wisdom and wealth in the Amidah prayer

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, money, direction

[O Ch 94 (2) Mishna Berura 12](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.94.2?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=en) suggests that in the Amidah one who wants to gain wealth turns his face northward or to gain wisdom turns southward.

I remember having found a source that suggests that in the blessing for wisdom one can turn his face south to get wisdom and in the blessing for sustenance  one who wants to gain wealth can turn his face northward. In this way one can get both advantages - wisdom and wealth.

Can someone redirect me to that source please?

Comment: I remember hearing the same thing, and I've also been looking for a source since...

Comment: @Shmuel At the bottom of your link there is: During shemonah esrei, the Bobover Rebbe would sway from right to left and then from left to right. He explained, "While I daven I keep in mind that I wish to draw down spiritual blessings when I sway towards my right and physical bounty when I sway towards my left.”

Comment: are you looking for a way to gain both wisdom and wealth in the Amida prayer, or are you looking for the specific method of turning different directions in different blessings. If the former, here is a story with the Maggid of Mezritch that illustrates his solution: https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/379858/jewish/Beyond-Space.htm

Answer (score 4):

The [DafDigest on Bava Basra 25](https://dafdigest.org/masechtos/BavaBasra/BavaBasra%20025.pdf) quotes the sefer קובץ אמרי קודש, ניסן תשס"ח, עי in which a story from the Bobover Rebbe is related:

> During shemonah esrei, the Rebbe would sway from right to left and
> then from left to right. When someone asked him why he always swayed
> in exactly that manner he explained, “In [Bava Basra 25 we find that
> one who wishes to be wealthy will daven towards the north, while one
> who wishes to become wise will daven towards the south.](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.25b.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) As you know,
> we daven towards the east, and to my right is south and my left is the
> north. While I daven I keep in mind that I wish to draw down spiritual
> blessings when I sway towards my right and physical bounty when I sway
> towards my left.

Comment: Great. I still seek a reference to facing one way in "atto chonain" and the other way im "boraich oleinu".

Answer (score 0):

["Chukei Chaim"](https://cchaim.com/) told me that the practice of facing one way in "atto chonain" and the other way im "boraich oleinu" is ascribed to Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach zatzal.